# Accessing ArcGIS server based services outside of firewall

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to know the options for making ArcGIS based map services (ArcGIS Server 10) available to users who are out of our firewall, mostly field crews and users with web access in the field. These services are not secured at the moment. I am looking for some feedback from users who have implemented this. Thanks Jay

Comment: Either VPN or open up your firewall.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing a reverse proxy? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32634

Comment: We are looking into reverse proxy but this will require us to add an addtional server but for now I am looking for a way to do this without reverse proxy option.

Comment: @jay Then as mapperz has said, your only options are to either open the required ports in your firewall for your ArcGIS server, or place your ArcGis Server in the DMZ. The first option if preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Mapperz suggestion is the best one: a reverse-proxy and with it running Linux and Apache, the investment is only in a box for the RP server. It doesn't latest and greatest PC either, a very simple box for a few hundred dollars will more than suffice. I do not recommend that you open up the ports on your firewall direct to your ArcGIS Server - unless the ArcGIS Server is inside your DMZ. Allowing internet access into your LAN would make most security administrators break out in a cold sweat!

Good luck

Comment: Within our IT environment, we have a standard configuration for server and it comes with a price. Are you sugegsting that we could use a regular pc to set up this or we need to have a server at the minumum.